# How get data from glucometers in J2ME using serial port?

Tags: java-me, serial-port

I have to do an application for a GPRS modem JAVA *(J2ME)* programmable that must interface with an electromedical device *(glucometer)*.

I have an input buffer and an output buffer on the serial port of the device.

When the application starts, I listen on the serial port and I receive from the glucometer one byte with the decimal code "5" which corresponds, to the ASCII table, the symbol of Enquiry and after 15 seconds I get the bytes "4" that corresponds to the End of Transmission.

To receive data from the glucometer I need to send an ACK signal *(acknowledge)* which corresponds to the byte "6".
I tried the following forms:

`outBuffer.write("ACK\r\n".getBytes()); //first without setting the charset and after I trying to set all the charset.`

I tried to send a byte buffer like this:

`byte[] bSend = new byte[] { 6 };
outBuffer.write(bSend); //(I tried also with the byte 10 (LF) and 13 (CR)).`

The result is that I can not receive data but I get ​​cyclically but only the values 5 and 4.

With all the software that can comunicate with serial port *(like Serial Monitor)* if I send an ACK message I receive data from glucometer correctly.

I think my problem is due to the value of the ACK coding in Java, someone can indicate any solution?

Answer (score 1):

As this seems to be a pretty low-level interface that uses ASCII control characters to do its communication I think you need to send these byte values verbatim, and without extra stuff like newlines or whatever.  This means that

```
byte[] bSend = new byte[] { 6 }; 
outBuffer.write(bSend);
```

Is the correct approach.  Now, this protocol looks a lot like ASTM E1381, so I checked [here](http://www.readbag.com/userportal-iha-dk-jrt-bayercontour-meterinterface) and paragraph 6.1.2 might be related to your problem:

> When the meter initiates the Establishment Phase, the meter determines
>   if the computer is connected by initially sending an `<ENQ>` character.
>   If the computer responds within 15 seconds by sending an `<ACK>`
>   character, the meter proceeds with Data Transfer Mode. If the computer
>   responds within 15 seconds with a `<NAK>` character, the meter sends an
>   `<EOT>` then attempts to enter Remote Command Mode, by looking for an
>   `<ENQ>` character from the computer.  Also see "Section 6.2 Remote
>   Command Mode Protocol". Any response within 15 seconds to the meter’s
>   `<ENQ>` other than an `<ACK>` or `<NAK>` character causes the meter to send
>   an `<EOT>`, delay one second, then send another `<ENQ>`. If the computer
>   does not respond within 15 seconds, then the meter sends an `<EOT>`,
>   delays one second, then sends another `<ENQ>` and waits again for a
>   response from the computer. **Note: One second after sending an `<ENQ>`,
>   the meter may enter a low power mode.  Thus, there is a possibility
>   that the first `<ACK>` sent by the computer is not read correctly.  In
>   this case, the meter responds with an `<EOT>`, delays one second, then
>   sends another `<ENQ>`.**

Emphasis mine, I guess that that's what's happening.  So, you should repeat sending another ENQ to get it into data transfer mode, assuming that that's what you want.

Comment: The situation is exactly the one presented.
I have read the same document as having the Bayer Contour XT.
I forgot to write before that I send an ACK in a cyclic manner to every message received by the meter, so I don't limit myself to only send an ACK, without results...

Comment: I am pretty sure the way of sending the ACK byte is correct.  If anyways possible have a look at the voltage levels used by your GPRS modem, maybe its Tx signal uses a voltage that cannot be reliably detected by the glucometer (easily done with an oscilloscope - see page 27 of the linked document for the voltage ranges that should work).  Also, having a serial port sniffer available would be very handy.

Comment: Maybe it helps to call flush()?

Comment: I thank you all for your contributions!Currently I'm not using the software directly on the GPRS modem but through an emulator on my PC.
I have tested this emulator, it works correctly because before trying to take data from glucometers I tried to query the GPRS modem with commands that I can also send via shell and I have no problem!
I already tried to use the method FLUSH.
It's a good idea to use a sniffer serial port. Do you know some software for Windows (possibly free)?

Comment: IMO software-only sniffers are not that useful for embedded work, so I can't recommend a product there, nowadays I mostly use a [Logic](http://www.saleae.com/logic) to analyze communications.  It's not free but it's a very versatile great little device that I can only recommend.  Downside, you need access to the TTL end of the communications (the "inside" of the line drivers), you cannot just clip it on an RS232 link.

Answer (score 0):

it should be 
byte bSend=(byte)0x6;
outBuffer.write(bSend);